# Compressing RData to Store in a Database

Tags: r

I would like to compress R data as much as possible to store it in a SQLite database. The most that I've been able to shrink the data so far is to save it as a RData file, then to load it.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make the data smaller?
2. Is there a way to create the same object without saving it to a file first?

```
# Make a big data object
carsList <- list(rep(cars,100))

# Trying serialize and collapse to string to store in SQLite database
object.size(paste(serialize(carsList, connection = NULL), collapse = ""))
168456 bytes

# Save and then load same data, collapse to a string to store in a SQLite database
saveTempFile <- tempfile()
save(carsList, file = saveTempFile)
object.size(paste(readBin(saveTempFile, what = "raw", n=1e7), collapse = ""))
1936 bytes
```

Comment: When you say "R data" do you mean rectangular data with consistent column classes like a data frame (as in your example) or do you mean generic R objects that may or may not be data frames?

Comment: The `.Rdata` file format has been optimized as a good compromise between file size and read-times. You can choose the compression level using `compress=` and `compression=` (arguments to [`save`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)), but beyond that you will likely find that is the best you're going to do for downright _size_, usually at the expense of taking longer to read in. What is the underlying reason you're trying to outsmart all of this? Storing an Rdata blob in a sqlite database seems not far from the [`.NORM` file format](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: "R data" would be a generic R object.

Comment: for storing to an object, I feel like `raw()` and `rawConnection(., "w")` should help (and then save to the connection), but I can't quite figure out how it works

Comment: I'd also ask whether you really need the files themselves in a database. Maybe you could put the files on a standard file storage service and just keep a pointer and metadata (name of file and whatever else you need) in the database. Databases generally aren't optimized for file / binary blob storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the `save` compression is pretty good, but you can specify `compression_level = 9` to have it work harder at making a smaller file.
On disk, I see `save(carsList, file = "default.rdata")` as 913 Bytes and `save(carsList, file = "compress.rdata", compression_level = 9)` as 721 Bytes. Following the `?save` pointer to the compression section of `?file` and taking their advice,

> For write-mode connections, `compress` specifies how hard the compressor works to minimize the file size, and higher values need more CPU time and more working memory (up to ca 800Mb for `xzfile(compress = 9)`). For `xzfile` negative values of compress correspond to adding the `xz` argument `-e`: this takes more time (double?) to compress but may achieve (slightly) better compression. The default (6) has good compression and modest (100Mb memory) usage: but if you are using `xz` compression you are probably looking for high compression.

`save(carsList, file = "xz_max.rdata", compress = "xz", compression_level = -1)` produces a 368 byte file.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the compression. Is there a way to have the compressed data as an object in R without saving to a file first, then reloading it?

Comment: Not that I know of. This is another reason why putting the actual files in the database as objects isn't the best idea. I'd recommend writing the file directly to a storage location (e.g., S3), and writing the file name and anything else you need to the database. This will keep your database performant and speed up your processing a lot because you won't need to read things into R as part of the save operation.